# Graphviz: control minimum rank of nodes in subgraph

Tags: graphviz

In the graph below, how do I move the ClassB subgraph to the right of ClassA aligned at the top? I.e. I want to increase the rank of the nodes in ClassB to 3.
I guess it might be possible using invisible dummy nodes, but I can't figure it out. Also I'm hoping there's a less "ad hoc" solution.

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR];
    0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3;
        subgraph cluster_SEM_SAD_analysis {
            graph [label="main"];
            main [label="main"];
        }
        subgraph cluster_ClassA {
            graph [label="ClassA"];
            ClassA__method1 [label="method1"];
            ClassA__method2 [label="method2"];
        }
        subgraph cluster_ClassB {
            graph [label="ClassB"];
            ClassB__method1 [label="method1"];
            ClassB__method2 [label="method2"];
        }
        main -> ClassA__method1;
        ClassA__method1 -> ClassB__method1;
        ClassA__method1 -> ClassA__method2;
        ClassA__method1 -> ClassB__method2
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `graphviz` that you want  the nodes in the *Class B* cluster on the level below *method2* of *Class 1*. You achieve that by introducing an invisble edge between them. This is not "ad hoc", but inherent `graphviz` logic.

Add, as a last line of your code

```
ClassA__method2 -> ClassB__method1[ style = invis, weight = 100 ];
```

and you get

[image]

which is probably what you want. Aligning the third cluster at the top is achieved by the `weight = 100` element.

Comment: Thanks. An invisible _edge_ was what I needed--not a node. But I would consider this ad hoc because it requires figuring out node with the greatest rank in ClassA and the node with smallest rank in ClassB and creating an edge between them. A more general way would be something like ` subgraph cluster_ClassB {minrank=3;...}` but I guess that doesn't exist in dot. Anyway, this solution is fine for now.